# specialization of a template who has a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I got the following template

```
template<class T, class U, bool(*function)(T)>
struct foo {
/.../
}
```

How do I create a specialization for it?
The spcialization should be like the following

```
template<>
struct foo<my_type_1, my_type_2,/*how do I handle this parameter?*/>
```

My main question is how do I handle the parameter of the funcion?

thanks in advance

Comment: What role does the third parameter play in your specialization?

Answer (score 2):

You handle it like you do any other argument in the template's argument list. `T` is a class (or other type), so you provide it with such (`my_type_1`). Same goes for `U`. The last parameter is a function which accepts an object of type `T` (which in your specialization is `my_type_1`) and returns a `bool`. So provide it with such:

```
template<class T, class U, bool(*function)(T)>
struct foo {};

struct my_type_1 {};
struct my_type_2 {};

bool my_func(my_type_1 m) {
    return true;
}

template<>
struct foo<my_type_1, my_type_2, my_func> {};
```

Comment: may I not specialyze the function? I don't need that, is just out of curiosity

Comment: @Linus What do you mean by "specialize the function?" You cannot specialize anything except a *template*, and you do so by providing specific possibilities for the template's parameters. You might have a function which *is* a template (a templated function), and you can specialize it in the exact same way that you specialize a struct, class, variable, etc (except you can't do partial specialization for a function).

Answer (score 1):

just add your function with my_type_1 as parameter and bool as return:

```
bool poo(my_type_1 X){
    return 0;
}
```

so your code must compile:

```
struct foo<my_type_1, my_type_2, poo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
// Your primary template
template <class T, class U, bool(*function)(T)>
struct foo;

// Some classes
struct my_type_1;
struct my_type_2;

// A function
bool my_func(my_type_1);
```

For partial specialization, it would be:

```
template <bool (*func)(my_type1)>
struct foo<my_type_1, my_type_2, func> { /*..*/};
```

For full specialization:

```
template <>
struct foo<my_type_1, my_type_2, &my_func> { /*..*/};
```

Comment: is This allowed in any standard, I m working on c++14

Comment: Yes for both forms.